# Should UIViewController subview properties be implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, properties, subview, option-type

Let's say I'm creating a custom subclass of `UIViewController` called `ViewController`.

I want to programmatically add to it the property `var textField: UITextField!`.

Should I make `textField` an implicitly unwrapped optional and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I agree with drewag. Even if you code will end up littered with '?' symbols :)

Comment: @Woodstock [drewag said to use non-optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28530848/242933), which don't require '?' symbols.

Answer (score 0):

No, avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals whenever possible. The only time you should use implicitly unwrapped optionals is when their initialization cannot happen during the initialization of your view controller. This is common when:

1. They are outlets you are connecting in a nib / storyboard file
2. They depend on some other object that is being loaded from the nib / storyboard

When you use implicitly unwrapped optionals you lose certain protections that Swift has added. Most importantly, you lose the compiler forcing you to initialize the property before you use it.

Comment: I just answered after linking to your post [here](http://www.drewag.me/posts/uses-for-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals-in-swift)! It seems to me like you're saying yes, but apparently not for programmatically constructed viewControllers?

Comment: @blacksquare, no, I am saying no except in the narrow circumstances above. Most of the time, a programatic subview's initialization is not going to depend on an IBOutlet. It can be initialized during the view controller's initialization and then attached to the view hierarchy in viewDidLoad without having to make it an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: Sure--I get that, but then you're repeating initialization for every initializer your viewController uses if you don't want to use implicitly unwrapped optionals. That doesn't sound ideal, does it? Best practice is probably just to use optionals then, no?

Comment: @blacksquare, most likely you can just initialize the property in place: `let myLabel = UILabel()`. I could see an argument for not wanting to reinitialize in a bunch of separate initializers, but I would argue that having a bunch of initializers is a code smell. Some of those should probably be converted to convenience initializers with one or two core initializers (probably one programatic and one from a coder)

Comment: Yeah, but what about the fact that it makes more sense logically to initialize a subview after the view has been loaded, not before, especially if the subview frame depends on the view bounds? @blacksquare your answer makes sense to me. I voted to undelete it.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I don't agree that it is more logical to wait to initialize the subviews. The dependency should always be on what is required for initialization. A subview does not, and should never actually depend on its superview for initialization because that breaks the entire composite nature of views. A single setting of a subviews bounds is rarely enough to properly place it anyway. Regardless, like i said in my answer, using an optional removes certain compiler protections, but ultimately it is a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should initialize it in `loadView`, not `viewDidLoad:`.
2. You can use `lazy` variables to avoid optionals for subviews, while effectively deferring initialization to `loadView`, or when the property is referenced before `loadView` is called, which brings us to:
3. I consider implicitly unwrapped optionals (and forced unwrapping) to be a code smell in all cases. It's *entirely* possible to access one of them before `loadView` is called, so they should be true optionals. Type and null-safety are *important*.

Declare a lazy variable like this:

```
private(set) lazy var imageView = UIImageView(...)
```

As a simple reference for point three:

```
let imageViewController = ImageViewController()
imageViewController.imageView.image = ...
```

This will crash if imageView is implicitly unwrapped instead of lazy non-optional.